# Using an SQL function when updating rows with Propel 2

Tags: php, mysql, sql, propel, propel2

I'm using Propel 2 and am trying to do a batch update of records. The following works as expected:

```
//UPDATE animal SET species='Duck';
AnimalQuery::create()->update(['Species' => 'Duck']);
```

However, I'm not sure what to do if I want to do something like the following:

```
UPDATE animal SET species=REPLACE(species, 'Mallard', 'Duck');
```

Is this possible using Propel?

Answer (score 1):

The following query has the same outcome as the query you state would meet your needs.

AnimalQuery::create()->filterBySpecies("Mallard")->update(['Species' => 'Duck']);

It will issue the following query.
UPDATE animal SET species='Duck' WHERE species='Mallard';

Does that meet your needs?